# LoRaWAN planning - do M gateways seem to suffice for N sensors & 1 [msg/hr]?

Tags: iot, theory, lora, lorawan

We have installed **`N`** LoRaWAN sensors and **`M`** gateways. These sensors require an acknowledgment message from the network server. Communication is carried out every hour in SF9 on the 915 MHz band. If the acknowledgment is not received, the sensor switches to a degraded mode and then communicates **`K`** times more, in order to catch the signal from the gateway.

In order to try to solve this problem, we have tried to increase the density of the gateway network.

What is the number of Gateways to add?

Comment: This sounds like a university exam question

Comment: The information you provide in your question is not enough to estimate the number of gateways you need to install. What you need to provide is the following: - Area to be covered [in km2], the morphology of the area [Dense Urban, Urban, Sub urban, Rural] - The location of your devices [indoor | outdoor | basement] - the average messages sent by one device   - the lowest acceptable cell edge data reat

Comment: Also you need the airtime of the messages and the number of channels supported by the gateways in order to estimate collision probability and throughput